# I am currently trying to write a ship code with discord.js but i can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I run the bot on Visual Studio Code and it goes normally, every other command, but when I try to run this ship command nothing happens, my bot doesn't send nothing and VS Code doesn't send me any errors.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('discord-reply');
const getMember = require('functions.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('hello mother')
    bot.user.setActivity('bia info')
});

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, prefix) => {
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == 'bia ship') { 
  let user = message.mentions.users.first()
  let RN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) 

  const UnLoveEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#A14EFF')
  .setTitle('Uhm.. There is not a match.  ')
  .setDescription(`'${message.author} shipped with ${user} gives ${RN}%'`)


  const LoveEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#A14EFF')
  .setTitle('Looks like we have a couple here!  ')
  .setDescription(`${message.author} shipped with ${user} gives ${RN}%`)


    if (RN > 50) {
    message.channel.send(LoveEmbed)
  } else {
    if (RN < 50) {
      message.channel.send(UnLoveEmbed)
    }
  }
}}
)};
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in DiscordJS v13, you have to specify you're sending an embed like this:

```
channel.send({ embeds: [ExampleEmbed] });
```

So in your case:

```
message.channel.send({ embeds: [LoveEmbed] });
//In stead of:
message.channel.send(LoveEmbed);
```

[Source](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)